# Applications of Algebraic Geometry in Evolutionary Game Theory 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, game-theory

Hello,

do you know any papers or books that use algebraic geometry in evolutionary game theory ?

Comment: i'm not sure what you have in mind, but have you read Sturmfels's article "Can biology lead to new theorems?" 

Comment: @jc: If I recall correctly, that paper did not deal with the game theory aspects. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps Datta's [papers](http://math.berkeley.edu/~datta/) and his thesis [Algebraic Methods in Game Theory](http://math.berkeley.edu/~datta/thesis.pdf) could be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a good place to start.  If someone knows knows about stuff please do not hesitate to tell me. 

Thank you mathphysicist. 